# Trying to call a .NET API function from F#

Tags: .net, f#

I am using a communications API (.NET) to interface with a USB to CAN adapter. In the past, I used C# but now I want to try F#. I started with a basic console application and am able to configure the driver because all the API calls, so far, take immutable constants as inputs. Now I am to the point where I have to call a .NET function that has inputs and outputs.

In C#, I call the function using code such as:

```
status = commlib.Comms.ReadData(int id, out msg, 100);
```

How would I call this from an F# program?

I have been searching but have not found the answer yet.

Comment: Exactly the same way as you would in C#.  Try it and see

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will give it a try. It just didn't occur to me to just try it that way lol    I would declare those variables (id and msg) as mutable then?

Comment: In general for this sort of question the best idea is to say what part you are stuck on.  Is it handling the `out`, referencing the library weird runtime behaviour etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming (best guess from the incomplete code you posted) the signature is actually:

```
int ReadData(int id, out string msg, int something);
```

Then you call it like so:

```
let mutable msg = ""
let status = ReadData(10, &msg, 100)
```

Comment: The `ref msg` part of your answer is not going to mutate the `msg` variable, but instead create a new reference cell, mutate it and then discard it. So you either need mutable variable and `&msg` or a ref cell declared upfront. See: http://luketopia.net/2014/02/05/fsharp-and-output-parameters/

Comment: You can just use F# byte array then. Arrays are mutable in F#, they are just .NET arrays

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I got the code to not give me errors. When I get back on my development system, I will try the code out. Thanks again!

Comment: I just wanted to follow up. I got the code running on my development system this morning and successfully read data from my CAN bus. Now on to concurrency :-)    Thanks again!

Comment: Another followup: As I am building up my program, I put this call in an Async block. Then I tried to wrap that in a function. You can't do that because of the mutable part. I changed everything to use ref (as in Tomas' posted link in the first comment) and that let me put this in a function. Thanks!